# C++ : User Input of Names and Scores, unknown number of names, compare scores

Tags: c++, arrays

I need some help with homework. I need to create a program that gets names from the user, then asks for 5 scores for those names. There is an unknown number of names being entered. After the user finishes entering each name and scores, the program needs to calculate the average score after dropping the high and low scores. For example, the user enters "Nick" w/scores 8,7,6,5,4. Scores 8 and 4 would be dropped, and the average would be calculated off of 5,6,7. 
My questions are:
How do I connect the input names with their corresponding scores?
How do I fix this error "Stack around the variable 'scoreArray' was corrupted?"
Below is the code I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double calcAvgScore(int, int, int, int, int);
int checkValid(int);
int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int);
int findHighest(int, int, int, int, int);

int main() {

    string contestant;
    int score, i, arrayPos = 0;
    int scoreArray[5] = {};
    double avgScore;

    cout << "Enter the name of the star. Enter Done if no more stars.\n";
    cin >> contestant;
    while (contestant != "Done" && contestant != "done")
    {
        for  (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter judge " << i << " score: ";
            cin >> score;
            checkValid(score);
            scoreArray[arrayPos] = score;
            ++arrayPos;
        }

        avgScore = calcAvgScore(scoreArray[0], scoreArray[1], scoreArray[2],
                                scoreArray[3], scoreArray[4]);
        cout << "Average Score " << setprecision(2) << fixed << avgScore << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the name of the star. Enter Done if no more stars.\n";
        cin >> contestant;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

double calcAvgScore(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4,
                    int score5) {
    int low, high, totalScore;
    low = findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    high = findHighest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    totalScore = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - low - high;
    double avgScore = double(totalScore) / 3;
    return avgScore;
}

int checkValid(int score) {
    while (score < 1 || score > 10)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid score: ";
        cin >> score;
    }
    return score;
}

int findLowest(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5) {
    int low = 11;
    int array[5] = { score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < low)
        {
            low = array[i];
        }
    }
    return low;
}

int findHighest(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5) {
    int high = 0;
    int array[5] = { score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > high)
        {
            high = array[i];
        }
    }
    return high;
}
```

corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

double calcAvgScore(int, int, int, int, int);
int checkValid(int);
int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int);
int findHighest(int, int, int, int, int);

int main() {

    string contestant;
    int score, i, y, arrayPos;
    int scoreArray[5] = {};
    vector<string> names{};
    double avgScore, maxAvg;
    vector<double> avgScoreVec{};

    cout << "Enter the name of the star. Enter Done if no more stars.\n";
    cin >> contestant;
    while (contestant != "Done" && contestant != "done")
    {
        names.push_back(contestant);
        arrayPos = 0;
        for  (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter judge " << i << " score: ";
            cin >> score;
            score = checkValid(score);
            scoreArray[arrayPos] = score;
            ++arrayPos;
        }
        avgScore = calcAvgScore(scoreArray[0], scoreArray[1], scoreArray[2],
        scoreArray[3], scoreArray[4]);
        avgScoreVec.push_back(avgScore);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the name of the star. Enter Done if no more stars.\n";
        cin >> contestant;
    }

    maxAvg = *max_element(avgScoreVec.begin(), avgScoreVec.end());
    y = find(avgScoreVec.begin(), avgScoreVec.end(), maxAvg) - avgScoreVec.begin();
    cout << "... and the winner is " << names[y] << " with a score of " << 
    setprecision(2) << fixed << maxAvg << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

double calcAvgScore(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, 
                int score5) {
    int low, high, totalScore;
    low = findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    high = findHighest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    totalScore = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - low - high;
    double avgScore = double(totalScore) / 3;
    return avgScore;
}

int checkValid(int score) {
    while (score < 1 || score > 10)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid score: ";
        cin >> score;
    }
    return score;
}

int findLowest(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5) {
    int low = 11;
    int array[5] = { score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < low) 
        {
            low = array[i];
        }
    }
    return low;
}

int findHighest(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5) {
    int high = 0;
    int array[5] = { score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > high)
        {
            high = array[i];
        }
    }
    return high;
}
```

Comment: `"Stack around the variable 'scoreArray' was corrupted?` For what input do you get this error?

Comment: I used the below suggestion of setting arrayPos = 0 before the for loop. that corrected it.

Comment: The code looks fine after your changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn using a debugger and step through your code, so you understand what is happening. The loop

```
while (contestant != "Done" && contestant != "done")
{
    for  (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter judge " << i << " score: ";
        cin >> score;
        checkValid(score);
        scoreArray[arrayPos] = score;
        ++arrayPos;
    }
    // ....
```

is dubious. First, if you don't type "done" or "Done", you keep incrementing `arrayPos`, and its value becomes larger than 4, so you end up accessing out of bounds. Second, `checkValid(score);` should be `score = checkValid(score);`, as otherwise `score` remains unchanged (it is local to the function `checkValid()`). If you want a resizable array, consider using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. Consider also using a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead.

Comment: Fixed the error I was getting. Is there any way to avoid using map? We're only a few chapters into our textbook (intro class) and it didnt mention map

Comment: @WillEstes You need to "simulate" it then, look into associative arrays, lookup tables or hash tables for more info. In your case you can just define two arrays, one with the names, storing `std::string`, one with the scores, storing `int`, and ensure that the i-th name is referred as `names[i]`, and the corresponding score is `scores[i]`.

Comment: So what I've done is create two vectors, one for names and one for avg score. How do I link the two and determine which name has the largest avg score? 
For example, Vector1.at(0) has an average score of Vector2.at(0). Then check all entries of avg score to determine the largest one and display it with the corresponding name

Comment: @WillEstes Well, you just make sure that `names[i]` correspond to `scores[i]`, that's how you connect them. So e.g. the player "John" is identified by `names[0]` and has scores `scores[0]`. I hope it makes sense. If you want, you can even create a `struct Player{string name; int score;};` and define a vector of `Player`s, but for this you need to know how to use `struct`s (or classes).

Comment: Unfortunately for this class we don't go into classes. I think I understand the concept of what I have to do, I just don't know the syntax. Would I use a for loop to connect `Names[i]` and `scores[i]`?

Comment: @WillEstes, yes, in a loop indexed by `i`, read the `Names[i]`, then in the same loop read the `scores[i]`. The latter is a vector, so you need an inner loop into which to read the scores. Try and you'll succeed eventually :). Something like: `for(int i = 0 ; i < numplayers; ++i){ cin >> name; Names.push_back(name); for(int j = 0; j < numscores; ++j){ cin >> score; scores.push_back(score);} }`.

Comment: Think I got it. I'll add an edit to the question, please let me know if you see anything wrong with it. I've tested it a few times and it seems to be working.

Comment: @WillEstes It seems right, make sure you test it extensively. Also, consider replacing `system("pause");` by `std::cin.get();`, as the former is non-portable (works only on Windows).

Comment: Awesome. Appreciate your help as well as @REACHUS . I dont know if the `system("pause")` is a professor preferred ending, but I'll keep your suggestion in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I connect the input names with their corresponding scores?

You can use `std::map<string, double>` to map from name to input score (if average score is what you want to map into).

> How do I fix this error "Stack around the variable 'scoreArray' was corrupted?"

You should **zero your `arrayPos` variable**, at this point:

```
arrayPos = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Right now the `arrayPos` variable can easily go out of bounds (i.e. become > 4) and you will write onto the stack (i.e. where `scoreArray` has been allocated) though you are not allowed to.

Comment: I did your suggestion for arrayPos and it seems to have fixed the error I was getting. Is there any way to avoid using map? We're only a few chapters into our textbook (intro class) and it didnt mention map.

Comment: Well, you can simply store `std::string`s in one array and scores in another, such that corresponding indexes would match the same objects/contestants.

Comment: Ok, I think that one is a better option. So how do I declare an array for an unknown number of names? Right now visual studio is displaying an error for 'string name[ ];'

Comment: Right, if the number of names is unknown, use `std::vector`.

Comment: ok, so i inserted the following ' vector<string> names{}; ' and then added ' names.push_back(contestant); ' before the for loop started. I assume this is adding the names entered to the positions in the vector. How do I actually link the vector and array? To me it seems like after the for loop, the array that was just written is erased to input the next array.